# Having trouble getting 2.80 on Linux

Tags: installation, linux

I just installed Blender and noticed my screen looked a little different from the tutorial video, so I checked my version and the Linux discovery page had grabbed me 2.79...  Okay, so I tried downloading straight from Blender's site instead.  But when I went to open the install file, it kept telling me that Ark could not open the file.  I am like, a total Linux noob and having trouble Googling this.  Can someone help me figure out what plugin I need or otherwise explain why my window looks so different from the one in the tutorial???

Comment: What distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Before you install Blender 2.80 verify that your system meets the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

Since you're unfamiliar with Linux, I'd suggest you download the archive version. First check if you're using a 64 bit or 32 bit operating system. In case you don't know, either take a look at the system information in the system settings or open a terminal and run:

```
uname -m
```

If it returns `x86_64` you're running a 64 bit OS, 32 bit otherwise.

Then download the appropriate version and extract the archive:

- [Blender 2.80 Linux 64 bit](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2/)
- [Blender 2.80 Linux 32 bit](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-linux-glibc224-i686.tar.bz2/)

Navigate into the extracted directory and find the file named `blender`. That is the program you need to run. An alternative to the archive version is to install Blender through Steam.

In case these instruction aren't detailed enough, please leave a comment which states what Linux distribution you're using.

Comment: Someone in meatspace ended up helping me use a PPA to download the latest Blender.  I appreciate the help anyways.

Comment: You're welcome. Would've made step by step instructions with screenshots otherwise.